# Optimising my function for iterating out an unordered list of custom taxonomy terms

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy

I've created a function that generates an `<ul>` of my wordpress custom taxonomy terms, displaying `parent > child > second child` heirachy. Functionally it is working perfectly and replaces my old hard-coded menu.

The problem is I'm inexperienced and recognise it as an ugly, inefficient function but could not figure out how to make it better. I tried use 'While()' loops to simplify things but came unstuck. Could someone help me understand how to improve this. The final output (including CSS and jQuery to collapse deactivated menu items) is included below.

```
//Display Navigation Menu

function taxonomy_nav(){

  //Get Parent Terms
  $getParents = [
    'taxonomy'     => 'kernal_category',
    'parent'        => 0,
    'number'        => 0,
    'hide_empty'    => false  
  ];

  //Assign parent terms to variable
  $parent_terms = get_terms( $getParents );  

  //Loop through parent terms
  foreach ( $parent_terms as $parent_term ) {   

    //Store children terms 
    $childrenCheck = get_term_children( $parent_term->term_id, $parent_term->taxonomy );

    //If parent term has children...
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $childrenCheck ) && ! empty ( $childrenCheck ) ) {

      //Output parent term and start new children list
      echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link( $parent_term ) .'">'. $parent_term->name.'</a>';
      echo '<ul>';

        //Loop through child items and output name
        foreach ( get_terms( 'kernal_category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $parent_term->term_id ) ) as $child_term) {

            //Check if children have children
            $secondChildrenCheck = get_term_children( $child_term->term_id, $child_term->taxonomy );

              //Generate list for second children
              if ( ! is_wp_error( $secondChildrenCheck ) && ! empty( $secondChildrenCheck ) ) {

                echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child_term ) . '">' . $child_term->name.'</a>';
                echo '<ul>';

                //If child has child, look through child
                foreach ( get_terms( 'kernal_category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $child_term->term_id ) ) as $second_child_term) {

                 echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link( $second_child_term ) . '">'.$second_child_term->name . '</a></li>';       

                }

                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</li>';       

              } else {

              echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link( $child_term ) .'">'. $child_term->name.'</a></li>';

              }
        }

      echo '</ul>';
      echo '</li>';

    } else {

      echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link( $parent_term ) .'">'. $parent_term->name.'</a></li>';

    }     

  }
```

[image: Final List =]

Comment: When you're looking for improvement of a working solution, [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a more fitting platform.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise that was a thing. I will post and then delete here.

Comment: Implementing this yourself is rather the wrong approach to begin with - WordPress has several `Walker` classes already for this kind of functionality.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I was unaware of those but will look into how they can simplify. I did look liberally on here for suggestions but didn't have much success.

Comment: This question has been moved to code review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/239184) and an answer to it was accepted.